Is "なんだというんだ。" some kind of expression?
A character says something shocking so the narrator says this:
再び、異様な沈黙が戻ってくる。
なんだというんだ。
"The strange silence returns" and なんだというんだ。. What does it actually mean? Is the narrator confused?  Is he trying to say the silence means everyone is confused?

To break down:

何: what
だ: (copula)
と: (quotative particle)
いう: say
ん: (explanatory-の)
だ: (adds a dubious or confrontational tone, see: Ending Questions with だ)

So the literal translation is "What do you say it is!", but you can understand this as a set phrase meaning "What the hell is this all about?" or "This is insane!"
Variants include なんだってんだ, なんだっての, なんだっていうのよ, etc.
